# Join two tables by dates returning data grouped by date

Tags: mysql, date, join, group-by

I have two tables `tbl_live_links` and `tbl_total_links` both have two colums  `dateSubmitted`, `pid` and `linkSubmitted` and they do not have any relation between them. But the requirement is to fetch sum of links submitted in each month.

I am using these queries::

```
    SELECT dateSubmitted
         , sum(`linkSubmitted`) as total 
      FROM `tbl_total_links` 
     where pid = 1
     group 
        by `dateSubmitted` 
     order 
        by `dateSubmitted` DESC 
     limit 0,6
```

Result of this query is::

```
dateSubmitted total
2015-08-10       20
2015-07-06       56
```

AND

```
SELECT dateSubmitted, sum(`linkSubmitted`) as live FROM `tbl_live_links` where pid = 1 group by `dateSubmitted` order by `dateSubmitted` DESC limit 0,6
```

Result of this query is::

> dateSubmitted
>   live
>
> 2015-08-10
>   59
>
> 2015-07-06
>   78

AND I want result like this

> dateSubmitted
>   total
>   live
>
> 2015-08-10
>   20 59
>
> 2015-07-06
>   56 78

Both tables can have multiple submission for particular month but I want sum of all links submitted in a month from both the tables

Comment: Datesubmitted looks like a relation to me

Comment: You can say because we have to fetch total links submitted from both the tables having same date.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT tbl_live_links.dateSubmitted, sum(tbl_live_links.`linkSubmitted`) as live ,sum(tbl_total_links.`linkSubmitted`) as total
     FROM `tbl_total_links`, `tbl_live_links` 
     where pid = 1
     and tbl_live_links.dateSubmitted = tbl_total_links.dateSubmitted
     group 
        by `tbl_live_links.dateSubmitted` 
     order 
    by `tbl_live_links.dateSubmitted` DESC 
 limit 0,6
```

Comment: No, it's not working, I have already tried this. In this query suppose we have 2 records in a month then it will return double of the sum of that month.

Comment: unknown column `tbl_live_links.dateSubmitted` in order clause

Answer (score 0):

here you can try with the simple joins conditions, hope this can resolve your prob, the join condition i have took from your two statement,

```
select
    dateSubmitted,
    sum(tlink.linkSubmitted) as total,
    sum(llinks.linkSubmitted) as live
from
    tbl_total_links tlink
    inner join tbl_live_links llinks on llinks.pid = tlink.pid
where
  llinks.pid = 1
group by 
    tlink.dateSubmitted,
    llinks.dateSubmitted
order by
    tlink.dateSubmitted,
    llinks.dateSubmitted
    desc
limit 0,6
```